# How to reuse system icons in TabBarController?

Tags: ios, xcode

How to reuse system icons in TabBarController but give them a custom name (e.g., I want to have *Search* icon with *Movies* label instead of *Search*)?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 12 and earlier, you can't. The documentation for creating a UITabBarItem with a system item states:

> The title and image properties of the returned item cannot be changed later.

So you need to use your own icon that looks like the standard system icon.

In iOS 13 this is much easier because you can use SF Symbols. Then you can create a "regular" tab bar item with the search ("magnifyingglass") image from the SF Symbol and whatever title you want.

Comment: Is there an open source pack of icon that looks similar to default ones?

Comment: A simple google image search will lead you to lots of icons. Be sure you look at the icon's license before you copy it.